# How do I restore data from a couchbase 2.5.1 cluster into a couchbase 3.0.3 cluster?

Tags: couchbase

I have two couchbase servers, one is 2.5.1 and one is 3.0.3. I can easkily backup all buckets in the 2.5.1 server, but I cannot restore them into the 3.0.3 server. Is this even possible? I read in the documentation [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/upgrading.html) that if you're upgrading, the install will automatically detect the format and convert it, is there such a standalone tool that I could use on my own? I certainly don't see one that seems glaring in my couchbase/bin directory.

Comment: seen this? http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbtransfer_tool.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cbtransfer tool can do this or you could use XDCR to go between clusters as well.

Just because I am curious, what error do you get when you do a cbrestore into the 3.0.3 cluster with the backups from the 2.5.1 cluster? this should work in theory.